# R ggplot colour labelling time series based on class

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, classification, timeserieschart

I have two time series as below:

```
y1 <- mvrnorm(50, c(3,1), matrix(c(0.5,0.3,0.3,0.3),2,2))# 2-D bivariate normal
y2 <- mvrnorm(50, c(1,0), matrix(c(2,.1,.1,1),2,2))# another 2-D bivariate normal
y <- rbind(y1,y2) # append the second to the end of the first
```

I plot these with ggplot:

```
yd <- as.data.frame(y)
g<- ggplot(data=yd) +
    geom_line(aes(x=1:nrow(yd), y=yd$V1, colour= "TS1"))+
    geom_line(aes(x=1:nrow(yd), y=yd$V2, colour= "TS2"))+
    scale_colour_manual(name= "Levels",
                        values = c("TS1"= "black",
                                   "TS2" ="blue"))+
    labs(title="Two time series")+
    xlab("Time") +
    ylab("Levels") +
    theme(legend.justification = c(1, 0), legend.position = c(1, 0))
```

[image: Figure 1]

I then run a classifier which creates a numeric vector of class labels for each time point. Below I plot the posteriors and provide the label vector.

[image: Figure 2]

```
dput(labels)
c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)
```

I want to be able to colour-code Figure 1 with respect to the class labels derived from the above labels vector. To be clear, I want to be able to see what state (class) I am in at any given time, rather than just seeing the state shift boundaries. The most intuitive way of doing that I think is **to change the background colour (e.g. from gray to orange) when state shifts to class 2.**

What is the best way of achieving this in ggplot? I am obviously open to other solution suggestions.

Comment: Draw a vertical line with `geom_vline()` at time shift?

Comment: But if I have let's say 3 states, I won't know whether the shift was from state 1 to state 3 OR from state 1 to state 2. (I get your point though will add this to the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like a background color with `geom_ribbon`.

```
# creating background data
df_bg <- data.frame(x = c(0, rep(which(as.logical(diff(labels))), each=2), length(labels)), 
                    ymin = 1.1*min(yd$V1, yd$V2), 
                    ymax = 1.1*max(yd$V1, yd$V2), 
                    fill = factor(rep(unique(labels), each=2)))
# plot 
g <- ggplot(data=yd, aes(x = seq_along(V1))) +
  geom_ribbon(data = df_bg, 
              aes(x = x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, fill=fill), alpha=.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y=V1, color="TS1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=V2, color="TS2")) +
  scale_colour_manual(name= "Levels",
                      values = c("TS1"= "black",
                                 "TS2" ="blue"))+
  labs(title="Two time series") +
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab("Levels") +
  theme(legend.justification = c(1, 0), legend.position = c(1, 0))
```

Comment: Perfect! :)   I haven't yet tried to understand the code `?geom_ribbon` but am I right in assuming this works for N states as well?

Comment: I think the `fill = factor(rep(unique(labels), each=2))` bit in the call is hard-coded, i.e. it doesn't work if there was another state shift following the depicted two. If I understand your code correctly, a more general solution is: `fill = factor(rep(labels[c(which(as.logical(diff(labels))), length(labels) )], each=2))`