# ggplot2 geom_ribbon to colour-label time series

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I want to colour-label a time series using `ggplot2`. I have two distinct states (classes) as given by the `labels` vector below and I want to super-impose this on top of a plot of IBM `Close` prices.

Below is my attempt, which unfortunately can not produce distinctively colour-coded regions by state. I am mainly having trouble with using `geom_ribbon()`:

```
library(TTR)
library(ggplot2)

data <- getYahooData("IBM", start = 20130101, end = 20150101, freq = "daily")
df <- data.frame(data)
df$Date <-as.Date(row.names(df),"%Y-%m-%d")        

# plot colour coded states on top of the original signal
dput(labels)
c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)

# colour and class labels to be used by geom_ribbon
df_bg <- data.frame(x = c(0, rep(which(as.logical(diff(labels))), each=2), length(labels)), 
                    ymin = min(df$Close, na.rm = TRUE), 
                    ymax = 1.1*max(df$Close, na.rm = TRUE), 
                    fill = factor(rep(labels[c(which(as.logical(diff(labels))), length(labels) )], each=2))
                    )

ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=1:nrow(df), y=diff_ma )) +
  labs(title="IBM 2-State HMM") +
  geom_ribbon(data = df_bg, 
              aes(x = x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, fill=fill), alpha=.2) +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Levels") +
  theme(legend.justification = c(1, 0), legend.position = c(1, 0))
```

As you can see below, rather than distinct red and blue filled regions, this `geom_ribbon` code produces a mixture of the two.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I think it is the `fill` column in `df_bg`, but I am not entirely sure. Also, if I wanted to plot by Date in the x axis, can I still use `geom_ribbon` to colour label?

P.S: This question is related to my previous one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362267/r-ggplot-colour-labelling-time-series-based-on-class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `group` argument to your data and `geom_ribbon` call. Otherwise it groups by color and just uses the filling color from the minimum to the maximum value for each of your colors.

```
# colour and class labels to be used by geom_ribbon
df_bg <- data.frame(x = c(0, rep(which(as.logical(diff(labels))), each=2), length(labels)), 
                    ymin = min(df$Close, na.rm = TRUE), 
                    ymax = 1.1*max(df$Close, na.rm = TRUE), 
                    fill = factor(rep(labels[c(which(as.logical(diff(labels))), length(labels) )], 
                                      each=2)),
                    grp = factor(rep(seq(sum(as.logical(diff(labels)), na.rm=TRUE)+1), each=2))
)
# 
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=1:nrow(df), y=Close)) +
  labs(title="IBM 2-State HMM") +
  geom_ribbon(data = df_bg, 
              aes(x = x, ymin=ymin, y=180, ymax=ymax, fill=fill, group=grp), alpha=.2) +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Levels") +
  theme(legend.justification = c(1, 0), legend.position = c(1, 0))
```

EDIT: In order to change the `x-axis` to `Date` format, you can use the `Date` in your `geom_line` command and change the x of your `df_bg` to a `Date`.

```
# colour and class labels to be used by geom_ribbon
df_bg <- data.frame(x = df[c(1, rep(which(as.logical(diff(labels))), each=2), length(labels)), "Date"], 
                    ymin = min(df$Close, na.rm = TRUE), 
                    ymax = 1.1*max(df$Close, na.rm = TRUE), 
                    fill = factor(rep(labels[c(which(as.logical(diff(labels))), length(labels) )], 
                                      each=2)),
                    grp = factor(rep(seq(sum(as.logical(diff(labels)), na.rm=TRUE)+1), each=2))
)
#
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=Close)) +
  labs(title="IBM 2-State HMM") +
  geom_ribbon(data = df_bg, 
              aes(x = x, ymin=ymin, y=180, ymax=ymax, fill=fill, group=grp), alpha=.2) +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Levels") +
  theme(legend.justification = c(1, 0), legend.position = c(1, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to use `Date` in the x axis here?

Comment: Thanks again @shadow. One final question. If the number of states is > 2, which parameters of `df_bg` do I need to adjust? `x` gives the state boundaries, so it shoud be fine. `ymin`, `ymax` should also be fine. Do I need to modify `fill` and `grp`?

Comment: In case of more than 2 states, you cannot use `abs` in the group definition, but have to use `as.logical` (as before). I changed that in the answer. Otherwise it should still work.